# Android 2D Graphics are Choppy

Tags: android, performance, 2d, android-canvas, surfaceview

**SurfaceView.LockCanvas() is taking anywhere from 15ms to 75ms to complete. Is there any way to fix this, or to make it less sporadic?**

Background: I am new to Android 2d graphics development, so I started with the jetboy example and altered it to simply scroll one of its bitmaps across the screen (using a velocity vector and a `System.currentTimeMillis()` based difference to get the elapsed time).

The bitmap will scroll perfectly for a second or two, but intermittently pauses giving a choppy look.

After some debugging I think the problem is caused by the fact that `SurfaceView.LockCanvas()` takes anywhere from 15ms to 75ms to return the `Canvas` -- Even when there is no significant update code running and nothing is being drawn to the canvas.

The following is my debug code. Starting with the Jetboy example, I replaced the `run()` method with this code:

```
public void run() {     
        while (true) {
            time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            elapsed_cycle = time - prev_time;
            prev_time = time;
            if (elapsed_cycle > 35.0){
                Log.d(LOCKING, String.valueOf(elapsed_cycle) + MSAFTER + String.valueOf(count) + CYCLES);
                count = 0;
                }
            else count++;

            elapsed_draw += elapsed_cycle;

            if (elapsed_draw > 30){
                elapsed_draw -= 30;

                c = null;
                try {c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {Log.d("ERROR", "Lock Canvas 1.");} 

                if (c != null) {mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);} else {Log.d(ERROR, "Couldn't unlock.");System.exit(0);}
            }
        }
    }
```

So, the code does two things: 1) Simply tries to lock than unlock the canvas every 30ms. 2) If any single cycle (iteration) of the while loop takes longer than 35ms than a LogCat output is generated. Running this code gives the following LogCat output:

```
07-03 13:07:44.587: D/LOCKING(4805): 39ms, after 24 cycles.
07-03 13:07:44.757: D/LOCKING(4805): 39ms, after 5 cycles.
07-03 13:07:44.838: D/LOCKING(4805): 50ms, after 1 cycles.
07-03 13:07:45.048: D/LOCKING(4805): 44ms, after 5 cycles.
07-03 13:07:45.799: D/LOCKING(4805): 74ms, after 41 cycles.
07-03 13:07:49.432: D/LOCKING(4805): 36ms, after 215 cycles.
```

And here is a taste of the unfiltered LogCat:

```
07-03 13:33:11.058: D/BatteryService(712): update start
07-03 13:33:11.068: D/BatteryService(712): level:99 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 4332 temperature: 315 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17303207 invalid charger:0
07-03 13:33:11.078: D/LOCKING(5804): 39ms, after 40 cycles.
07-03 13:33:11.088: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(896): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
07-03 13:33:11.088: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(896): onReceive() - level:99
07-03 13:33:11.088: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(896): onReceive() - plugged:2
07-03 13:33:11.088: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(896): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
07-03 13:33:11.088: D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(896): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
07-03 13:33:11.118: W/AlarmManager(712): FACTORY_ON= 0
07-03 13:33:11.128: E/MtpService(1013): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
07-03 13:33:11.128: E/MtpService(1013): battPlugged Type : 2
07-03 13:33:11.128: D/LOCKING(5804): 49ms, after 0 cycles.
```

Now for some random observations I've made:

1. If I introduce a delay in the while loop using `Thread.sleep()` then the `LockCanvas()` time takes even longer, scaling with the delay amount.
2. I still see this problem using the `Invalidate()`/`onDraw()` drawing-process of the Snake example.
3. I see this same choppiness in a similarly simple libgdx project, though the application runs perfectly on the desktop.
4. I'm debugging on a (physical) Samsung Galaxy SIII.
5. Giving `lockCanvas()` a "dirty" `Rectangle` of 1 pixel width and 1 pixel height doesn't speed anything -- I thought it may be happier to do less work.
6. In the manifest file, setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` doesn't help.
7. Again in the manifest file, setting supports-screens `android:anyDensity="true"` doesn't help.
8. Building to an .apk and installing doesn't help.
9. I see the choppiness when running the unaltered jetboy game.

For those who are not familiar with the jetboy example, here is the `onCreate()` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // get handles to the JetView from XML and the JET thread.
    mJetBoyView = (JetBoyView)findViewById(R.id.JetBoyView);
    mJetBoyThread = mJetBoyView.getThread();

    // look up the happy shiny button
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mButtonRetry = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    mButtonRetry.setOnClickListener(this);

    // set up handles for instruction text and game timer text
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    mTimerView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

    mJetBoyView.setTimerView(mTimerView);

    mJetBoyView.SetButtonView(mButtonRetry);

    mJetBoyView.SetTextView(mTextView);
}
```

And the thread is started here:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // start the thread here so that we don't busy-wait in run()
    // waiting for the surface to be created
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

Even if you don't know how to fix this issue, if you don't see this issue on your own setup then I'd love to hear from you about how you are drawing and how you are debugging.

Comment: I know it's years later, but any luck? I'm running into the same issues

Comment: TL;DR: Nope, no luck. I gave up and moved to Unity years later... saw similar issues, but was able to fix it (in Unity). I want to give you a longer explanation because I do feel like I have more info to share, but Im not sure when I'll have time to write it all out... but, stay tuned!